# php mysql update table option listbox

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, html-select, primary-key

I am trying to update my table with values selected into the option select box but it doesn't update the selected row when I click saved.
id is the primary key of my table. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

**dovarclass.php**

```
<form class="rnd5" action="SaveClassVariant.php" method="post" name="import" id="import">
<?php
    $Query='SELECT id,Location,`Coding`, `Amino Acid Change` AS ProtDesc,GMAF, `Coverage`, `% Frequency` AS Freq FROM mytable';
    $QueryPerform=mysqli_query($conn,$Query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
     while($rowPanel =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryPerform)) {
          $id = $rowPanel["id"];
        echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='".$rowPanel["id"]."'&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;<select name='list[$id]' id='list[]' size='4' multiple='multiple'>
        <option value='Classe 1'>Classe 1</option>
        <option value='Classe 2'>Classe 2</option>
        <option value='Classe 3'>Classe 3</option>
        <option value='Classe 4'>Classe 4</option>
        <option value='Classe 5a'>Classe 5a</option>
        <option value='Classe 5b'>Classe 5b</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;".$rowPanel["Location"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowPanel["Coding"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowPanel["ProtDesc"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowPanel["GMAF"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowPanel["Coverage"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowPanel["Freq"]."&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        }
?>
<input type="submit" name="sendEcht" value="Sauvegarder" />
</form>
<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

in my **savevariantclass.php** I am trying to get my id by doing it:

```
if($_POST){

$VariantClass = $_POST['list'];
foreach(array_values($VariantClass) as $key =>$value )
{
$j=$key+1;
echo $j;
$UpdateVariantClass='UPDATE mytable SET VarClass="'.$value.'" where id='.$j.'';
mysqli_query($conn,$UpdateVariantClass) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
}//end of $_POST
```

Comment: The `$Query=...` line in *dovarclass.php* has no quote at the end of the string. Your query shouldn't work... but from what you say I gather it does. How is that possible? In *savevariantclass.php* `$tablename` is unknown, so it cannot work.

Comment: i forgot the quote when I copy my code here. I edited

Comment: You also edited the second problem. How can we help you if the code isn't exactly what you're actually using?

Comment: the code is exactly what I have

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code. Where to start? First of all, all your selects have the same id. Why do you use `[..]` in select names and ids? So, when you look at `$_POST['list']` it is quite unpredictable what you will get. Then you throw away any keys with `array_values()`, why? Anyway, I would start by dumping what is actually in `$_POST` and make that work. After that I would worry about getting it in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve my issue.
To get the id I use array_search.

```
$class=$_POST['list'];

foreach ($class as $value) {

$k = array_search($value,$class);
$sql='UPDATE mytable SET VarClass='.$value.' where id='.$k.'';
echo $sql.'<br/>';

}
```